# Looking to save output of a stored procedure into a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to save the output of a stored procedure (any column counts, error messages, etc.) into a variable that I can insert into a column of a table for a log. Pretty much the same was what is reported in the results pane in SSMS. If I use `SQLCMD` with the `-o` option, that gives me what I want, but into a file, and I don't really want to use `sqlcmd`.

Is there an easy way to do with without building `TRY/CATCH` logic?

Addendum:  I don't have the NO_COUNT set to ON. What I am looking for is what is returned in the Messages pane of SSMS if running the stored procedure manually (which includes PRINTS, counts (## rows(s) affected, errors, etc.)

Comment: Actually I deleted my answer. Because on rereading your question, I don't think you're looking for arbitrary output. You're looking for specific output. You may want to work on improving your question. Try providing a sample procedure with the output you're interested in and more specific information about where you want that information stored.

Comment: Smarter to use try catch to log any errors via an insert and then just explicitly return what you want as results.

Comment: Can you provide details of the information you are looking to log ?

Comment: please explain with some examples